# How to allow user to resize widget?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, swt

I'm using SWT Java. I'd like to implement layout that is resizable by user.

For example File Tree on left side, text editor on right side and user can change size ratio between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for a [`Sash`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FSash.html) widget! ([Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#sash))

Comment: Especially I needed SashForm, not Sash. But it has helped me a lot. Thanks